# will vs going to in the if-sentence

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, will-vs-going-to

According to Cambridge's [*Advanced Grammar in Use*](https://www.academia.edu/33666045/Advanced_grammar_in_use), (Unit 11D) only ***will*** is correct in the following sentences, but not ***going to***,

> If you look carefully, you'll (***not*** are going to) find writing scratched on the glass.
>
> If you move to your left, you'll (***not*** are going to) be able to see the church.

because in a situation like the above, you are describing a future event that follows another.

I would argue that in almost all conditional situations a future event may follow another, and therefore it is not a reason to distinguish ***will*** and ***going to***.

So my question is: Can ***going to*** be used here or not?

Comment: You are right.  I will reword my question.

Comment: People use *are going to* in this context all the time. It sounds very slightly strange to me personally, but not at all unusual. Given that it *is* used so often, I think it's impossible to make the claim that it's wrong. Language and grammar is fluid and necessarily changes over time and use. It may have been something that wasn't done in the past, but it's certainly done now. This seems more a prescriptive statement than anything of practical value. For all intents and purposes, I don't think this can be called wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have now read the passage in question which says:

> We can use  **will** or  **going to**  with little difference in meaning in the main clause of an if-sentence when we say that something (often something negative) is conditional on something else - it will happen if something else happens first

...

> However, we use **will** (or another auxiliary), not **going to**, when we describe a future event that follows another. Often 'if' has a meaning similar to 'when' in this kind of sentence.

I think that it may be that the use of "will" rather than "going to" in such a case results in better writing, but that construction is in my view used too frequently to call this a rule. Such a declaration, with no particular reason given, feels very prescriptive to me. So I have to disagree with this source about this "rule".

Answer (score 0):

I think the textbook is correct in that native English speakers are more likely to use *will* than *going to* in these sentences, but I think the reason they give is wrong.

Both of these sentences are essentially *advice*. We generally use *will* if we are using an *if* sentence to give somebody advice. (I don't know if this is a special case of a more general grammatical rule or not.)

> If you stop smoking, you will live longer.

But we are perfectly willing to use *are going to* when "one future event may follow another".

> If they close the airport, they are going to have to find places for all the passengers to stay.